# Get selected option text in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get the selected text of a select, and compare the value within an expect. I have the following code:

```
expect<any>(select_seller.getText()).toEqual('SELLER 1')
```

But what I got as result is the text of the whole list of sellers, as follows:

```
Expected ' SELLER 2
SELLER 1
SELLER 3
SELLER 4
 ' to equal 'SELLER 1'.
```

What I've tried:

- `select_seller.getAttribute('text')`, the result is `undefined`.
- `select_seller.getAttribute('value')`, the result is: `Expected '1: Object' to equal 'SELLER 1'.`

EDIT:

The html code for the select is:

```
<select id="field_seller" [(ngModel)]="o.seller">
  <option [ngValue]="sellerOption" *ngFor="let sellerOption of sellers">
      {{sellerOption.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Anyone has an idea on this? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML also

Comment: @demouser123 added. Thanks a lot for the suggestions

Comment: What selector are you using for `select_seller`?

Comment: @demouser123 css selector: select#field_seller, this shouldn't  be the problem as the element is found correctly, but not the selected text value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be not correct because I've haven't tested this yet but you can do something like

```
function getSelectedText(select) {
  return select.getAttribute('value')
    .then(function (i) {
      return select.element(by.css('option[value="' + i + '"]')).getText();
    });
}

getSelectedText(element(by.id('select_id'))).then(...)
```

Or more simple way:

```
function getSelectedText(select) {
    return select.element(by.css('option:checked')).getText();
}

getSelectedText(element(<locator of select>)).then(...)
```

Comment: I had to modifiy it just a little bit! But this aproach works, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.